# Linking kernel module with a static lib

Tags: linux-kernel, kbuild

I'm trying to link my kernel module with an external static lib, like this:

```
obj-m += my_prog.o
my_prog-objs := some/path/lib.a
# all the standard targets...
```

For some reasone, the above Makefile doesn't compile my_prog.c at all, and the resulting module doesn't contain its code. Certainly, if I remove `my_prog-objs` line, `my_prog.c` gets compiled.

What's wrong with such an approach in a Makefile?

Answer (score 4):

You must create a synthetic name as well as the source file and it's object name.  You can not use `my_prog.o` directly as there are rules to make it from source.  Here is an sample,

```
 obj-m += full.o
 full-src := my_prog.c
 full-objs := $(full-src:.c=.o) lib.o # yes, make it an object.
```

Libraries are only supported from some special directories.  Your object should be named `lib.o_shipped` and placed in the same directory.  So, you need to take the external library and provide it locally as a *shipped* version.  You need two object files; one is your compiled 'C' code/driver and the other is it linked together with the library.

---

The above is relevant to 2.6.36 kbuild infra-structure.  The current documentation is in [modules.rst section 3.3 Binary Blobs](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/kbuild/modules.rst#n283).  I think the technique above will still work for libraries as opposed to just objects.

Comment: Obviously, you only want needed objects in the `lib.o_shipped`.  You can create this from the `lib.a` by extracting all objects with `ar` and then doing an incremental link with `ld -r`.  At least that is what I think I did...  If someone has a better way, I am listening :)

Answer (score 3):

When you create the `my_prog-objs` list, you tell kbuild to use only the object files in that list. kbuild will no longer compile `my_prog.c`, and including `my_prog.o` in `my_prog-objs` results in a circular dependency. Instead, you need to create a unique `obj-m` and include both `my_prog.o` and `/path/lib.a` in its `objs` list. For example:

```
obj-m += foo.o
foo-objs += my_prog.o /path/lib.a
```

Took me about 2 hours to figure out why my module was doing nothing!

Answer (score 1):

You're overriding the default `my_prog-objs`, which is just `my_prog.o`.  Instead of replacing the contents with the library, add the library to the default:

```
my_prog-objs := my_prog.o some/path/lib.a
```

Hopefully you're not trying to link against a general userspace library... that won't work at all in kernelspace.

Comment: Then it complains about circular dependency on `my_prog.o` and skips it anyway.