# How do I link a static library when building a kernel module?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I want to build a Linux kernel module `foo.ko` from an existing file `foo.c` and a static library `support.a`. The library `support.a` is compiled from Rust so there is no `support.c`.

I've used the following Makefile

```
KERNEL_DIR := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build

obj-m += foo.o
foo-obs += support.a

all:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNEL_DIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules V=1
```

It seems that `support.a` is not linked; there are warnings that the functions called from `foo.c` (and implemented in `support.a`) are undefined.

*Update 0*: the [Makefile](https://github.com/tathanhdinh/rustyvisor/blob/master/Makefile) works on Ubuntu LTS (I've tested on 18.04 and 14.04) but not on Fedora (both 29/30). The output in case of Fedora is:

```sh
...
make -C /lib/modules/5.1.11-200.fc29.x86_64/build SUBDIRS=/public/Github/rustyvisor modules
make[1] : on entre dans le répertoire « /usr/src/kernels/5.1.11-200.fc29.x86_64 »
Makefile:205: ================= WARNING ================
Makefile:206: 'SUBDIRS' will be removed after Linux 5.3
Makefile:207: Please use 'M=' or 'KBUILD_EXTMOD' instead
Makefile:208: ==========================================
  LD [M]  /public/Github/rustyvisor/rustyvisor.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
WARNING: /public/Github/rustyvisor/rustyvisor.o(.init.text+0xbb): Section mismatch in reference from the function init_module() to the function .exit.text:rustyvisor_exit()
The function __init init_module() references
a function __exit rustyvisor_exit().
This is often seen when error handling in the init function
uses functionality in the exit path.
The fix is often to remove the __exit annotation of
rustyvisor_exit() so it may be used outside an exit section.

WARNING: "rustyvisor_core_unload" [/public/Github/rustyvisor/rustyvisor.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "rustyvisor_load" [/public/Github/rustyvisor/rustyvisor.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "rustyvisor_core_load" [/public/Github/rustyvisor/rustyvisor.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "rustyvisor_unload" [/public/Github/rustyvisor/rustyvisor.ko] undefined!
  LD [M]  /public/Github/rustyvisor/rustyvisor.ko
make[1] : on quitte le répertoire « /usr/src/kernels/5.1.11-200.fc29.x86_64 »
```

*Update 1:* There is very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22150812) but this question is to ask why the Makefile doesn't work on Fedora but I discovered that it works on Ubuntu.

Comment: I'll say - unpack the static library and just add all the .o files to `obj-m`.

Comment: Thank you. Is is the single possibility for this case?

Comment: It is very unlikely that user-space library (especially non-C one) will work in the kernel space. Kernel doesn't provide many functions which are used by user-space code.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: I understand that but basically `support.a` contains very basic functions which should work in every space (user, kernel), e.g. add, mul, etc.

Comment: Your *Makefile* might be not correct. I usually do the way like `obj-m += foo-module.o\n foo-module-objs := foo.o support.a`. Note as well typo you made at least here.

Comment: @0andriy thank you. It still doesn't work. Actually, this makefile works on Ubuntu but not on Fedora, I still don't understand why.

Comment: Extend your post with real output shown (where errors happen).

Comment: @0andriy: I've updated the post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linking kernel module with a static lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22150812/linking-kernel-module-with-a-static-lib)

Comment: Can you also put output of `objdump -h your_lib_a_file`?

Comment: It's quite verbose, so I put it [here](https://gist.github.com/tathanhdinh/48f68ec9a0cc8288ff2bcf16babc0463)

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found a workaround for the problem (but I still don't understand why). On Fedora, the library name `support.a` should be changed to `support.o`, then the linker works!!!